# Container of pointers to derived class from template class with common ancestor as template argument

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, containers, unique-ptr

I have a super class that models a `Measurement` and two derived classes: `PointCloudMeasurement` and `ImageMeasurement`.

Another templated super class, `Handler<MeasT>` defines the interface to process the measurement.

Two handler classes, `PointCloudHandler` and `ImageHandler` specialize the `Handler` class with the corresponding measurement types as template arguments.

I would like to keep track of all the handlers using a container of pointers to the super class, and call the appropriate method depending on the derive type of handler at hand.

Here is the code ([link](http://cpp.sh/5zgkh)):

```cpp
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Measurement {
public:
  uint64_t time;
  virtual ~Measurement() {}
};

class PointCloudMeasurement : public Measurement {
public:
  uint64_t n_points = 64*1024;

};

class ImageMeasurement : public Measurement {
public:
  uint64_t n_pixels = 640*480;

};

template<class MeasT = Measurement>
class Handler {
public:
  virtual void addMeasurement(MeasT& m) = 0;
};

class PointCloudHandler : public Handler<PointCloudMeasurement> {
public:
  void addMeasurement(PointCloudMeasurement& m) override {
    std::cout << m.n_points << std::endl;
  }
};

class ImageHandler : public Handler<ImageMeasurement> {
  void addMeasurement(ImageMeasurement& m) override {
    std::cout << m.n_pixels << std::endl;

  }

};


int main(void){
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Handler<Measurement>>> handlers;

  handlers.push_back(std::make_unique<PointCloudHandler>());
  handlers.push_back(std::make_unique<ImageHandler>());

  PointCloudMeasurement pcm;
  ImageMeasurement im;

  handlers[0]->addMeasurement(pcm);
  handlers[1]->addMeasurement(im);
}
```

which gives me:

```cpp
In function 'int main()':
50:59: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Handler<Measurement> > >::push_back(std::_MakeUniq<PointCloudHandler>::__single_object)'
50:59: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/vector:64:0,
                 from 4:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:913:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<Handler<Measurement> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Handler<Measurement> > >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::unique_ptr<Handler<Measurement> >]
       push_back(const value_type& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:913:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::_MakeUniq<PointCloudHandler>::__single_object {aka std::unique_ptr<PointCloudHandler, std::default_delete<PointCloudHandler> >}' to 'const value_type& {aka const std::unique_ptr<Handler<Measurement> >&}'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:931:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<Handler<Measurement> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Handler<Measurement> > >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::unique_ptr<Handler<Measurement> >]
       push_back(value_type&& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:931:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::_MakeUniq<PointCloudHandler>::__single_object {aka std::unique_ptr<PointCloudHandler, std::default_delete<PointCloudHandler> >}' to 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Handler<Measurement> > >::value_type&& {aka std::unique_ptr<Handler<Measurement> >&&}'
51:54: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Handler<Measurement> > >::push_back(std::_MakeUniq<ImageHandler>::__single_object)'
51:54: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/vector:64:0,
                 from 4:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:913:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<Handler<Measurement> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Handler<Measurement> > >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::unique_ptr<Handler<Measurement> >]
       push_back(const value_type& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:913:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::_MakeUniq<ImageHandler>::__single_object {aka std::unique_ptr<ImageHandler, std::default_delete<ImageHandler> >}' to 'const value_type& {aka const std::unique_ptr<Handler<Measurement> >&}'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:931:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<Handler<Measurement> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Handler<Measurement> > >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::unique_ptr<Handler<Measurement> >]
       push_back(value_type&& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:931:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::_MakeUniq<ImageHandler>::__single_object {aka std::unique_ptr<ImageHandler, std::default_delete<ImageHandler> >}' to 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Handler<Measurement> > >::value_type&& {aka std::unique_ptr<Handler<Measurement> >&&}'
```

I don't understand why the pointer conversion does not work, since all the derived classes inherit from a `Handler<MeasT>` where `MeasT` is a derivation of `Measurement`.

I've seen similar questions but most of them keep the template even in the derived class (which I don't) or refer to the CRTP. However, the CRTP uses directly the derived class as template argument, while here I'm using a different derived class.

Comment: But a `PointCloudHandler` *definitely isn't* a `Handler<Measurement>`! A `Handler<Measurement>` has `addMeasurement(Measurement&)`, but a `PointCloudHandler` only has a `addMeasurement(PointCloudMeasurement&)`. You can pass e.g. a `ImageMeasurement` to the former but not the latter, but a subclass should be useable wherever the superclass is. Therefore, `PointCloudHandler` is not a subclass of `Handler<Measurement>`.

Answer (score 0):

Just think that C++ compiler is going to substitute the class name when we template. 
So your hash map declaration is translated in this way
std::vector>> handlers; --> std::vector> handlers;
means the compiler will automatically create a "templated class" from class template Handler as below

```
class Handler_Measurement {
  public:
   virtual void addMeasurement(Measurement& m) = 0;
 };
```

but when compiler sees handlers.push_back(std::make_unique()); it creates the following templated classes.

```
  class Handler_PointCloudMeasurement {
  public:
   virtual void addMeasurement(PointCloudMeasurement& m) = 0;
 };

  class PointCloudHandler : public Handler_PointCloudMeasurement {
    public:
      void addMeasurement(PointCloudMeasurement& m) override {
         std::cout << m.n_points << std::endl;
      }
    };
```

and for handlers.push_back(std::make_unique()); the compiler creates
        class Handler_ImageMeasurement {
         public:
            virtual void addMeasurement(ImageMeasurement& m) = 0;
         };

```
     class ImageHandler : public Handler_ImageMeasurement{
       void addMeasurement(ImageMeasurement& m) override {
         std::cout << m.n_pixels << std::endl;
       }
      };
```

From the hand crafted code sample you can see that the base classes are different. So a solution like below may help you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Measurement {
 public:
uint64_t time;
virtual ~Measurement() {}
virtual void display() = 0;
 };

 class PointCloudMeasurement : public Measurement {
  public:
uint64_t n_points = 64 * 1024;

void display()
{
    std::cout << n_points << std::endl;
}

  };

  class ImageMeasurement : public Measurement {
   public:
uint64_t n_pixels = 640 * 480;

void display()
{
    std::cout << n_pixels << std::endl;
}
  };

  class Handler {
  public:
virtual void addMeasurement(Measurement& m) = 0;
  };

  class PointCloudHandler : public Handler {
  public:
void  addMeasurement(Measurement& m) override {
    m.display();
}
  };

  class ImageHandler : public Handler {
void  addMeasurement(Measurement& m) override {
    m.display();
}
  };


  int main(void) {
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Handler>> handlers;

handlers.push_back(std::make_unique<PointCloudHandler>());
handlers.push_back(std::make_unique<ImageHandler>());

PointCloudMeasurement pcm;
ImageMeasurement im;

handlers[0]->addMeasurement(pcm);
handlers[1]->addMeasurement(im);
 }
```

Also your derived classes are different in data member wise. The only common thing about them is "they are a measurement type" but they don't have nothing in common.

I hope it helps.